# Shintani's unpublished paper on automorphic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, shimura-varieties

I'm trying to find Shintani's preprint:

Shintani T., On automorphic forms on unitary groups of order 3, unpublished, 1979.

It seems to be impossible to find, even though several authors quote it. I would also appreciate other references treating the theta-lift for the pair $(U(2),U(3))$ (possibly with a classical perspective).

Thank you.

Comment: What is supposed to be in there that you need?  Have you tried Murase-Sugano?

Comment: The theta-lift for the pair (U(2), U(3)). I haven't looked that up, thank you.

Comment: Murase-Sugano's Compositio paper studies FCs of Kudla lifts for quasi-split pairs.  They give a cf. there to another of their papers for Shintani's work, so maybe  that has what you want?

Comment: Maybe this reference is useful : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.0131.pdf .